# Django keeps adding ' character to first cell of my data so it can't store it in the model

Tags: python, django, pandas

I'm going nuts. Whatever I do, Django adds a ' character to the start of the first field of my data.

I have a df that looks like so:

```
    Year   JAN   FEB   MAR   APR   MAY   JUN   JUL   AUG   SEP   OCT   NOV  \
0    1910   6.1   7.2   8.9   9.6  14.5  17.1  17.3  16.9  15.6  12.5   6.9   
1    1911   5.8   6.5   7.5   9.7  16.2  17.8  21.7  21.4  17.3  12.4   8.2   
2    1912   6.0   7.5   9.1  12.5  14.4  16.0  18.4  15.0  13.7  11.6   8.4   
3    1913   6.7   7.2   8.5  10.4  13.8  16.5  17.6  18.5  16.5  13.5  10.6   
4    1914   5.6   8.7   8.4  13.2  13.8  17.6  18.5  19.1  17.0  12.9   9.1   
5    1915   5.9   6.4   7.7  10.8  15.1  18.0  16.9  17.7  17.0  11.9   6.0   
6    1916   9.2   5.7   5.5  11.1  14.1  14.5  18.3  19.2  16.0  12.9   8.8   
7    1917   2.7   3.8   6.1   8.4  16.3  17.5  19.3  17.1  16.2  10.7   9.9   
8    1918   6.4   8.4   8.7  10.1  16.2  16.6  18.4  18.3  14.3  11.5   8.5 ...
```

I have a function that puts it into a model:

```
def add_to_db(weatherstats_df):
print(weatherstats_df)
for row in weatherstats_df.itertuples():
    # print(row)
    year = int(str(row.Year).strip('\''))
    print(year)
    measurement = row.Measurement
    location = row.Location

    ikey = 0

    for key, month_or_season in WeatherStatistics.MONTH_OR_SEASON:
        ikey += 1
        value = row[ikey]
        if (value == "---"):
            value = None

        WeatherStatistics(
            year=year,
            measurement_type=measurement,
            location=location,
            month_or_season=key,
            value=value,
        ).save()
```

The model looks like this:

```
year = models.IntegerField(
        default=0,
        validators=[MaxValueValidator(9999), MinValueValidator(0)],
    )
```

Every time I run this, no matter how I try to strip the ' from the year, I still get an error like this:

could not convert string to float: "'1910"

I must be doing something dumb, but I can't figure out where I went wrong?

Environment:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/weatherstats/wales

Django Version: 1.11.7
Python Version: 3.6.3
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'weatherstats']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/Users/davidthompson/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/davidthompson/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _legacy_get_response
  249.             response = self._get_response(request)

File "/Users/davidthompson/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/davidthompson/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/davidthompson/Documents/Web_Projects/Weather/src/weatherstats/views.py" in download_weather_stats_wales
  37.     weatherstats_df = parse_url_df(loc, loc_data, weather_attr)

File "/Users/davidthompson/Documents/Web_Projects/Weather/src/weatherstats/data_parsing.py" in parse_url_df
  32.         add_to_db(weatherstats_df)

File "/Users/davidthompson/Documents/Web_Projects/Weather/src/weatherstats/pandas_operations.py" in add_to_db
  62.                 value=value,

File "/Users/davidthompson/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  808.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

File "/Users/davidthompson/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  838.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)

File "/Users/davidthompson/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _save_table
  924.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)

File "/Users/davidthompson/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _do_insert
  963.                                using=using, raw=raw)

File "/Users/davidthompson/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  85.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/davidthompson/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _insert
  1076.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)

File "/Users/davidthompson/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1106.             for sql, params in self.as_sql():

File "/Users/davidthompson/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in as_sql
  1059.                 for obj in self.query.objs

File "/Users/davidthompson/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in <listcomp>
  1059.                 for obj in self.query.objs

File "/Users/davidthompson/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in <listcomp>
  1058.                 [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]

File "/Users/davidthompson/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in prepare_value
  998.             value = field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=self.connection)

File "/Users/davidthompson/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in get_db_prep_save
  770.                                       prepared=False)

File "/Users/davidthompson/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in get_db_prep_value
  762.             value = self.get_prep_value(value)

File "/Users/davidthompson/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in get_prep_value
  1781.         return float(value)

Exception Type: ValueError at /weatherstats/wales
Exception Value: could not convert string to float: "'1910"
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback. Note, there are no floats involved in the year; are you sure it's that field that is causing the problem?

Comment: Yeah it's odd that it wants a float coz I didn't tell it to use a float! I get this in the errorlog - Internal 
  File "...miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1781, in get_prep_value
    return float(value)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: "'1910"
[29/Nov/2017 17:45:27] "GET /weatherstats/wales HTTP/1.1" 500 175801

Comment: Posted full traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should iKey be initialised to 1 rather than 0?   There are two non-float cols.

Ie, ikey = 1 before loop

Answer (score 0):

Just use a better way to sanitize the years:

```
import re
year = int(re.search(r'\d+', row.Year).group())
```